# NativeScript Angular ngClass is not working

Tags: angular, nativescript, ng-class

I have a DockLayout and two css classes. I change state.sideDrawer.isOpen but element's class does not change. When I `console.log` its class I see that first class it gets stays still. I tried setting its class in .ts file and it worked. But I need ngClass to work. What could be wrong?

I am using latest Angular CLI(7.2.1) and Nativescript(5.1.0).

Here is the Playground link : https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=oCeLRd

```
   <DockLayout #sideDrawer stretchLastChild="false" [ngClass]="{'sideDrawerOpen': state.sideDrawer.isOpen == true, 'sideDrawerClosed': state.sideDrawer.isOpen == false}" style="background-color: #3c3f47;width: 600px;padding: 0 0 5px 15px;"></DockLayout>
```

CSS:

```
@keyframes sideDrawerOpen {
   from  { transform: translate(-500, 0);}
   to { transform: translate(0, 0);}
}

@keyframes sideDrawerClosed {
   from  { transform: translate(0, 0);}
   to { transform: translate(-100, 0);}
}

.sideDrawerOpen{
   animation-name: sideDrawerOpen;
   animation-duration: 2s;
   animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.sideDrawerClosed{
   animation-name: sideDrawerClosed;
   animation-duration: 2s;
   animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

Comment: Can you share a Playground sample of same? Also let's know which platform you are testing this now?

Comment: I added requested links and information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your swipe event was executing outside Angular context, you must either use event binding in your HTML template Or use [Renderer2](https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2) to add add event listener to the [ElementRef](https://angular.io/api/core/ElementRef) in order for Angular to perform change detection.

[Here is the updated Playground.](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=oCeLRd&v=19)

Comment: It works but I did not understand it at all. You put trigger('sideDrawerAnimate',) there but you did not specify the element to animate. How does it know what to animate? And more importantly, what do you mean by executing outside Angular context?

Comment: I think you are confused between different methodologies, sine you have mentioned `ngClass` on the element, the animation takes place on the element whenever the new class is assigned. The alternative option is doing it via TS & Animation apis. You don't have to use both.

Comment: I know realized that those trigger stuff do not contribute the solution. You only put swipe event on the element. Why did you put animation stuff in Component though?

Comment: I didn't put it, it was your code. You could remove those, not actually required.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with a {N}-Angular app. For me the issue was because I had defined the `ngClass` css class above the default class in the .css file so it was getting imported first and overwritten by the default one. Switching the order of the classes solved the issue for me